# Averaging two channels with Python

Tags: python, channel, multi-channel, stereo-signal

I am trying to convert a stereo audio into a mono one by averaging both channels with Python.

My audio is stored in `sound` and I calculate the average using `np.mean(sound,axis=1)`. However, if I play the averaged audio, I am no longer able to hear the original sound: I hear a kind of random noise.

Here is the original sound:

https://voca.ro/1jpm8QCjVdyf

And this is what happens when I compute the average of both channels:

https://voca.ro/18hyBN4GneXW

The code that I use to play the audios is:

```
Y = np.mean(sound,axis=1)
obj = sa.play_buffer(sound,2,2,fs)
obj2 = sa.play_buffer(Y,1,2,fs)
```

And the original sound has the following format:

[image]

My question is: why does that happen? How should average the channels correctly?

Thanks,
Arnau.

Comment: The original sound file contains identical data on both channels. I therefore assume something went wrong with loading the file, since the array depicted in the screenshot contains (largely) different values in both channels.

Comment: @applesoup I used `scipy.io.wavfile.read(path)` to read the audio files.

Comment: As @Peter K. mentioned in a comment: `scipy.io.wavfile.read` does not support mp3 files. Therefore, I don't understand - did you convert the mp3 file to a wav file before reading in Python?

Comment: @applesoup No, the audio that I uploaded is not the original sound, I recorded what I was coming out from my speakers with the voice recorder of my computer and uploaded.

Comment: Ah, I see, @Arnau. It would probably help everybody here if you uploaded the actual audio file that you're trying to process.

Comment: @applesoup You're right, sorry about that. It's this one: https://voca.ro/1ojiJPK7x5Qh

Comment: Thanks, @Arnau. While the two channels are different know, the file that can be downloaded via the link you gave, again, is an mp3 file. That may be due to the hoster that potentially converted your original (wave?) file to mp3. Can you confirm the original file is in wave format so we can make sure `scipy.io.wavfile` is the correct module to use?

Comment: @applesoup Yes, it's a .wav file. I uploaded again to Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GGYP4Mg8qS7vdlMRnse9XK4rPz7R96OP/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Just doing

```
np.mean(y,axis=0)
```

seems to work for me.

But to really check I'd need to know how you loaded the file.  My code below.

---

## Code only

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import soundfile

y, sr = librosa.load('Q76477.mp3', mono=False)

ymean = np.mean(y,axis=0)
soundfile.write('Q76477_output.wav', ymean, samplerate=22100)
```

Comment: To load the file, I use `fs, sound = wavfile.read(path)` by importing `from scipy.io import wavfile`.

Comment: @Arnau That doesn't seem to let me read the mp3 file you shared.